# Joomla! 3.3.6 - JQuery validation plugin using remote method

Tags: jquery, validations

I'm trying to validate against a remote request, but the result is pulling in template info as well - throwing off my true/false response.  This works fine outside of Joomla, but I'm not finding a way of fixing it in Joomla.

http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

**Jquery:**

```
jQuery( "#modalform" ).validate({
    rules: {
        chosen_domain: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 4,
            remote: "index.php?option=com_component&task=checkDomain&tmpl=component"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        chosen_domain: {
            required: "Required input",
            minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, at least {0} characters are necessary"),
            remote: jQuery.validator.format("{0} is already in use"),
        }
    }
});
```

**Response:**

```
  <body class="contentpane">
    <div id="window-mainbody" class="window-mainbody">
      <div id="system-message-container">
    </div>

      "false"
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: What happens if you add `&format=raw` after `&tmpl=component`?

Comment: That did it, thanks!  I should have seen that... Make it a comment, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `&format=raw` at the end of the URL so it will look like the following:

```
index.php?option=com_component&task=checkDomain&tmpl=component&format=raw
```

Hope this helps